# How to grab zxing scan results and use them?

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing, qr-code

I am a new in developing area. I am trying to deal with the results after scanning a QR image. I am using the Zxing library. Right now only the content string can retrieve any data. But I want to scan a qr image to get the URL, telno and a string /text(which will be a numbered amount).
Could you pls show that with an example how can i get the data for telno and text both and store in strings. For now there is only one SCAN_RESULT which is stored in contents, but how can I get multiple results at a time from one QR code.

```
private void onQrActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            paymentmsg.setText(contents);
            value_Qr = Float.parseFloat(contents);
            // Toast.makeText(this, format, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, one QR code will only have one content, which is in `SCAN_RESULT`. If you wish to have a strange QR code with multiple parts, that's fine, but you *still* will only get one `SCAN_RESULT` with whatever combined string you put in the QR code, and you will have to be the one to parse that string into whatever it is you put in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the result. The result is in the content string. parse the content string.
If your qr code is contact

```
if(contents.startsWith("BEGIN:")){

                    String[] tokens = contents.split("\n");

                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                        {
                        System.out.println(" "+tokens[i]);

                        if(tokens[i].startsWith("BEGIN:"))
                        {
                            Type= tokens[i].substring(6);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("N:"))
                        {
                             Name= tokens[i].substring(2);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("ORG:"))
                        {
                             Org= tokens[i].substring(4);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("TEL:"))
                        {
                             Tel= tokens[i].substring(4);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("URL:"))
                        {
                             Url= tokens[i].substring(4);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("EMAIL:"))
                        {
                             Email= tokens[i].substring(6);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("ADR:"))
                        {
                              Adr= tokens[i].substring(4);
                        }
                        else if(tokens[i].startsWith("NOTE:"))
                        {
                              Note= tokens[i].substring(5);
                        }

                        }
```

if your qr scannrd is url

```
else if(contents.startsWith("http://")||(contents.startsWith("www."))){

                    qr_url= contents;
```

if your qr scanned is location qr

```
else if(contents.startsWith("geo:")){

                    String delims = "[ , ?q= ]+";
                    String[] tokens = contents.split(delims);

                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(" "+tokens[i]);
                        if(tokens[i].startsWith(" geo:"))
                        {
                              qr_latitude= tokens[i].substring(4);

                        }
                    }
                    qr_latitude= tokens[0].substring(4);
                    qr_longitude=tokens[1];
                    geo_place=tokens[2];
```

And so on you can parse the result. Its all about how you can parse a string.

Comment: Then you're settled...make sure you accept this answer if you're satisified :)

Answer (score 0):

One QR code means one scan result, of course. You get back the string, raw bytes, and some other metadata. If you want to parse the string into components, you have to do it yourself, but you can re-use the `ResultParser` class from `core/` in your app to easily do so.

Comment: thanks, i later found that it is one msg format out of which I have to retrieve the strings in my way.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code below will help you :

```
    ParsedResult tmpParseVcard = ResultParser.parseResult(result.getResult());
                AddressBookParsedResult vcardParsedResult = (AddressBookParsedResult) tmpParseVcard;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VCARD" + Arrays.toString(vcardParsedResult.getPhoneNumbers()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Phone number", Arrays.toString(vcardParsedResult.getPhoneNumbers()));
                Log.e("Phone Type", Arrays.toString(vcardParsedResult.getPhoneTypes()));
```

//AddressBookParsedResult  - vcard
//SMSParsedResult - sms ... etc